# Laplace inverse of a differential equation with initial conditions: 2(dy/dt) + y =0 , y(0)=-3

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

1. The exercise:

[image]

2. Apply Laplace:

[image]

Is it correct?
Because I´m confused in 3 or 3s?

3. Finally this:

[image]

In this part how to apply Decomposition Partial Fractions ?
And how's continued with de System of Equations ?
Because with the valors of the variables I know that I have to remplace and apply inverse Laplace

HELP PLEASE !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$2y'+y=0 \\ y(0)=-3$$
Apply Laplace 's Transform:
$$2(sY(s)-y(0))+Y(s)=0$$
$$2sY(s)-\color {red}{2y(0)}+Y(s)=0$$
$$2sY(s)+6+Y(s)=0$$
$$Y(s)(2s+1)=-6$$
$$Y(s)=-\dfrac 6 {(2s+1)}$$
You made some little mistakes. At point 2. The initial condition is multiply by $-2$. So that $-2y(0)=6$.

Apply inverse Laplace Transform:
$$Y(s)=-\dfrac 3 {(s+1/2)} \implies y(t)=- 3 e^{-t/2}$$
Since the inverse Laplace Transform for $\dfrac 1 {s+a}$ is $e^{-at}$

Comment: How do you get that = -6?

Comment: it s simply $2y(0)=2*(-3)$ @ConstanzaBrevis

Comment: I knowed, THANKS !  so every time I have any number multiplying to dy/dt I have to multiply with the initial condition too?  And in this case don't´apply Partial Fractions?

Comment: Note that $2(sY(s)-y(0))+Y(s)=0 \implies 2sY(s)2y(0))+Y(s)=0$ @ConstanzaBrevis

Comment: You have a factor 2 in front of the y' so yes you have to multiply by that factor. I added a line for clarity in my answer.

Comment: And the 1/2 how do you get that?

Comment: You have $2s+1$ at the denominator so factorise the 2. Because the formula for the inverse laplace transform is for $1 / (s+a)$ So put the fraction in that form @ConstanzaBrevis

Comment: GOD!!! THANKS YOU SO MUCH !

Comment: You're welcome @ConstanzaBrevis

Answer (score 0):

Since 
$$ {l}\{ y(t) \} = s \, y(s) - y(0)$$
then 
\begin{align}
a \, y'(t) + y(t) &= 0 \\
a( s y(s) - y(0)) + y(s) &= 0 \\
(a s + 1) \, y(s) &= a \, y(0) \\
y(s) &= \frac{a \, y(0)}{a s + 1} = \frac{y(0)}{s + \frac{1}{a}} \\
y(t) &= y(0) \, e^{-t/a}.
\end{align}

Applying the condition and appropriate constant yields the result.